# a dynamic link on my calendar?

Tags: php, html, date, calendar

I am working on a calendar webpage. I have it set up so that I can advance by month and and I can chose dates and when I do, it includes an "event add" form that allows the user to add an event to the calendar.

I also have worked in colors so that one an event is added, the date turns blue but when there are 10 or more events, the date turns red.

I'd like to also make sure that when the date is red, that the link to add another event no longer appears.

Code below is for the colors of the cells, is there away for me to modify it to also prevent an action from being taken at all if 10 or more?:

```
if($counter % 7 ==0){
    echo "</tr><tr>";
}

$monthstring = $month;
$monthlength = strlen($monthstring);

$daystring = $i;
$daylength = strlen($daystring);

if($monthlength <= 1){
    $monthstring ="0".$monthstring;

}
if($daylength <= 1){
    $daystring = "0".$daystring;
}

$todaysDate = date("m/d/Y");
$dateToCompare = $monthstring. '/' .$daystring. '/' .$year;
echo "<td align='center' ";

if ($todaysDate == $dateToCompare){
    echo "class='today'";
} else {
    $sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM EventCalendar WHERE eventDate='".$dateToCompare."'";
    $noOfEvent = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sqlCount));
    if($noOfEvent >= 1 && $noOfEvent <=9){
        echo "class='event'";
    }
    else if($noOfEvent >= 10){
        echo "class='Full'";
    }   
}
```

`<?php
            if(isset($_GET['v'])){
                echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year =".$year."&v=true&f=true'> Add Event </a>";
                if(isset($_GET['f'])){
                    include("eventForm.php");
                }
                $sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM EventCalendar WHERE eventDate ='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'";
                $resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);
                echo "<hr>";
                while($events=mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
                    echo "Title: ".$events['Title']."<br>";
                    echo "Detail: ".$events['Detail']."<br>";
                }
            }
        ?>`

Comment: Show the code that writes the "add event" link. That may help.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Here is the code for the add event link.

`if(isset($_GET['v'])){
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year =".$year."&v=true&f=true'> Add Event </a>";
    if(isset($_GET['f'])){
     include("eventForm.php");
    }
    $sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM EventCalendar WHERE eventDate ='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'";
    $resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);
    echo "<hr>";
    while($events=mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
     echo "Title: ".$events['Title']."<br>";
     echo "Detail: ".$events['Detail']."<br>";
    }
   }`

Comment: Post that in your question.